# Searching files in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I want to search a file in Eclipse. What's the shorcut to open file search dialog box?

Comment: First result on Google http://www.allapplabs.com/eclipse/eclipse_shortcuts.htm

Comment: As BalusC and echox explained, there is no predefined keyboard shortcut for file search, so you can't find the answer by simply looking at the menu tree... I think, those many downvotes are a little too hard. Unknown downvoters, please have a look again...

Answer (score 127, accepted):

If you want to search in files: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and then choose tab `File Search`.

If you want to search for resources: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

If you want to search for Java types: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

If you want more shortcut keys: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: After having pressed Ctrl+H, the File Search tab may not be visible (at least this is the case in Eclipse Neon), in which case one has to press the small arrow to the top right to bring out the hidden panes.

Comment: This answer is not correct as it does not answer the question. The question was NOT, how can I find a file that contains a certain text. The question is: I want to search a file in Eclipse. What's the shorcut to open file search dialog box?

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+R would be the correct answer, the other parts of the answer distract from the core answer, I think

Comment: It's the correct answer when you want to search for resources.

Answer (score 12):

There is no default shortcut to open the "Search a File" dialog directly.

Anyway you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to open the "Search Dialog".

You can also use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to open the "Key Assist" which will show you all configured shortcuts as a kind of tooltip.

Pressing again <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> in the "Key Assist", you can directly configure your own shortcuts. Enter "File Search" for the filter and simply set your own key combination.

I often search for a file and want also to open it directly. So I use the "Search for Resource" Dialog called with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

Comment: CTRL + Shift + R is so handy in locating a specific file in the opened projects.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `Window`->`Preferences` menu and select the `General`-`Keys` tab to see and **change** any key binding.

Shortcut for this: Press two times <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

There's also a plugin called MouseFeed that shows all keyboard shortcuts for the menu operations you do. You could even set it to prevent you from using the menu alternative and force you to use the shortcut.

A good way to help you become quicker at using Eclipse.

Edit: The domain associated with the plugin seems to be gone now and replaced with a porn site. So at this point the status of the plugin is a bit unsure :)