# Eclipse shortcut for searching word in workspace

Tags: java, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [searching files in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957774/searching-files-in-eclipse)

How to search for a particular word in entire workspace in Eclipse?

Comment: ... please don't test our patience - your previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957774/searching-files-in-eclipse) included the answer to this one already...

Answer (score 22):

select workspace and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

In the "Search" menu there is a "File" option, which brings up a dialog. Fill in the word you are looking for and a pattern to restrict which files to search.

Entering "Search" into the help system would have got you this.

Answer (score 3):

Select the workspace in the package explorer, open the File Search dialog, enter the particular world and `*`as a file wildcard, restrict the search to the selection.