# Where to locate jspx files in my code

Tags: jspx

Hello All,

```
   <div id="Main">
    <a href="index.jspx">Admin Home</a>
    <a href="viewLogging.jspx">View Logging</a>
    <a href="viewCache.jspx">View Cache</a>
    <a href="viewSessions.jspx">View Sessions</a>
    <a href="logout.jspx">Admin Logout</a>
    </div>
```

Now I have the above code in my jsp file. If I try to locate the jspx files in my source code, I do not see them. Please help me by directing me on where can I find them.
FYI I am using struts 1.x, Velocity. Please let me know If I need to add more details.

Comment: are you using eclipse?

Comment: @ddb Yes I do. I tried opening resource using Cntrl+shift+R

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search in files: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and then choose tab `File Search`.

If you want to search for resources: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

If you want to search for Java types: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

If you want more shortcut keys: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

Also at [this link](http://www.allapplabs.com/eclipse/eclipse_shortcuts.htm) you can find a list of all eclipse shortcuts

I found at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2957782/3178454) a part of this solution

Comment: The question I am sorry isn't about how to locate files. I have tried all ways. What I am trying to convey is though I see inclusion of these jspx files , i do not see any such physical file in my source code. Was wondering as to how could it be that I am not able to locate the file but there is a reference