# How to search for file and file contents in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

I was using Netbeans and find the search is fairly simple, just right click and click on Find. It searched for file name as well as contents.

Just moved to Eclipse Mars2, there is no find on right click of project.

[image: Netbeans Eclipse]

There is Search on menu (CTRL+H) and when i clicked

[image: Eclipse Search]

In eclipse, I have multiple projects and i tried to search text in single java project but it keep on searching on multiple projects even if my project is selected.

Could anyone provide me direction for easy search in eclipse?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2957782/5156075

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957774/searching-files-in-eclipse

Comment: @JohnJoe
The link contains shortcuts with not much info; I am able to open menu where i can search file but when i search it searches in all projects, as mentioned in question. So how to make eclipse search in one particular project only. Like in file search i have no option to select projects

Comment: @Fairoz : Please refer above comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select the project you want and do ctrl+H (or Search->Search), select second tab(File search). Make sure "Selected resources" is selected. This searches for the containing text in all files matching the provided file name patterns in the selected project.
[image]